# Taking Screenshots from Stackoverflow using R

Tags: html, css, r, latex

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I take the answer from this stackoverflow post (from u/Michael Hardy): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62963/1296713

**Using R and the hyperlink (i.e. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62963/1296713 ), I want to take this answer (only the answer, not the whole post) and save it as a PDF document (with the latex included) from R itself. I am also fine with a png image.**

The final output should look like this:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot/readme/README.html
library(webshot)
webshot("https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62963/1296713", "r2.png")
```

This code ran, but this is including the whole webpage - not just the answer from u/Michael Hardy:

[image]

**Can someone please show me how to do this correctly? Maybe this can be done more easily using rvest/httr webscraping?**

Thanks!

- **Note:**

I also tried the following based on CSS selectors:

```
library(webshot)

url <- "https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62963/1296713"
selector <- ".s-prose.js-post-body"

webshot(url, "r2.png", selector = selector)
```

Comment: This might be relevant: a URL of the form `https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62963/...` loads a page where the anchor `#answer-62963` holds the answer.  In Chrome you can **Inspect** this element, and [**Capture node screenshot**](https://swimburger.net/blog/web/hidden-gem-take-screenshots-using-built-in-commands-in-chrome-edge#capture-node-screenshot) to download a `.png` of the answer specifically.

Answer (score 6):

Using {chromote} to png:

```r
ses <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()
ses$default_timeout <- 10*60
ses$Page$navigate(url = "https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62963")
ses$view()

doc <- ses$DOM$getDocument()
sel <- "#answer-62963"

nid <- ses$DOM$querySelectorAll(doc$root$nodeId, sel)$nodeIds
box <- ses$DOM$getBoxModel(nid[[1]])

ses$screenshot(selector = sel,
               cliprect = c(box$model$content[[1]],
                            box$model$content[[3]]+box$model$content[[6]],
                            box$model$width,
                            box$model$content[[1]]+box$model$content[[3]]))
```

[image]

Comment: @ Grzegorz: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I got this error:

Comment: > box <- ses$DOM$getBoxModel(nid[[1]])
Error in nid[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Please check what's returned as `nid`. Or/and modify the `selector`.

Comment: Here is what I get: > nid
list()

Comment: @stats_noob  Try terminating your R session, and then running this again.  I needed to reset things before it started working for me.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko Is there a way for **`chromote`** to run the Chrome command for [**Capture node screenshot**](https://swimburger.net/blog/web/hidden-gem-take-screenshots-using-built-in-commands-in-chrome-edge#capture-node-screenshot)?

Comment: @Greg, nothing I'm aware off. It's not a part of [chrome devtools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol). There is a SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715164/how-to-invoke-chrome-node-screenshot-from-the-console) using puppeteer and there is a *puppeteer* like package https://github.com/rundel/hayalbaz - maybe there is a way to combine it.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko  Before commenting, I actually poked around in both the [protocol docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol) and that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50715164), and it frustrated me to no end that the Chrome docs don't seem to describe what underlying command is run when you click "**Capture node screenshot**".  Does Chrome have some sort of history log, where you can examine the command after capturing via the GUI?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest but has some limittations is to exec the browser in headless mode for a PDF or a PNG.

Now a problem with headless is that, to add cookies or replies to a login prompt will need some JavaScript magic and that is why puppeteer is best option.

Anyway here is the output from the pure command line, we can easily trim off the top.
[image: --hide-scrollbars]

```
browser.exe --headless --screenshot=%cd%\output.png --window-size="600,1000" --hide-scrollbars https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62958/considering-brownian-bridge-as-conditioned-brownian-motion/62963#62963
```

In this case I used Opera manually [* see comment below, as to why Opera in a case like this] but normally use Edge or Chrome headless. This alternative will pull the whole set of **pages** as editable PDF, then cut and paste the searchable contents.

Here just searching for Brownian, in the one page after trimming.
[image]

```
browser.exe --headless --print-to-pdf=%cd%\output.pdf  --no-pdf-header-footer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62958/considering-brownian-bridge-as-conditioned-brownian-motion/62963#62963
```

[*]
Opera uniquely, in manual mode, can `save as PDF` **a whole** single HTML page, without page breaks. This makes it easier with PDF not to have to mess about with divisions. So you can edit/delete the unwanted content at will, with a good editor or PDF program).

Comment: @ K J : Thank you for your reply! I am pretty bad at understanding how command prompt works

Comment: I tried the following code in command prompt: (I checked and this file exists)

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf=%cd%\output.pdf --no-pdf-header-footer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62958/considering-brownian-bridge-as-conditioned-brownian-motion/62963#62963

Comment: But I got this error: C:\Users\me >[0313/230013.306:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(35)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

Comment: Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: thank you for your reply ... I cant find this folder in my computer.... i wonder if there is a way in R that can search all directories in your computer to find a certain file name /file extension ... and then store this name as a variable ... and then insert this variable name into the rest of the R code...