# Keeping Track of Coin Flips Even When They Are Not Flipped

Tags: r, simulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following problem:

- There are 100 coins: the coins are randomly initialized at turn=0 (i.e. 0.5 probability of heads and 0.5 probability of tails)
- At each turn, any given coin has a 0.5 probability of being selected and flipped
- When a coin is flipped, there is a 0.6 probability it will land on the same side that was facing upwards when flipped and a 0.4 probability of landing on the other side
- At the end of each turn, we check each coin (flipped or not flipped, does not matter). If a coin is heads up then +1 else -1
- We do this for 100 turns

**My Question:** For each of these 100 turns, for each of these 100 coins - I want to track the cumulative number of heads and the cumulative number of tails.

As an example, suppose coin43 was flipped 7 times:

- heads, tails, not selected, not selected, heads, not selected, tails

Then, the scores would be:

- +1 , -1, -1, -1, +1, +1, -1

And at the most recent turn,  the cumulative numbers would be:

- 3 heads and 4 tails

First, I initialized the coins:

```
num_coins <- 100
num_turns <- 100
coins <- sample(c(-1, 1), num_coins, replace = TRUE)
cumulative_heads <- matrix(0, nrow = num_turns, ncol = num_coins)
cumulative_tails <- matrix(0, nrow = num_turns, ncol = num_coins)
```

Next, I tried to write the bulk of the simulation code:

```
# Simulation
for (turn in 1:num_turns) {
  if(turn > 1){

    cumulative_heads[turn,] <- cumulative_heads[turn-1,]
    cumulative_tails[turn,] <- cumulative_tails[turn-1,]
  }
  for (coin in 1:num_coins) {
    # Check if coin is selected
    if (runif(1) < 0.5) {
      # Flip the coin
      if (runif(1) < 0.6) {
        # Coin lands on the same side
        coins[coin] <- coins[coin]
      } else {
        # Coin lands on the other side
        coins[coin] <- -coins[coin]
      }
    }
    # Update cumulative counts
    if (coins[coin] == 1) {
      cumulative_heads[turn, coin] <- cumulative_heads[turn, coin] + 1
    } else {
      cumulative_tails[turn, coin] <- cumulative_tails[turn, coin] + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I created a data frame to store the results:

```
results <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = num_coins, nrow = num_turns))
names(results) <- paste0("coin", 1:num_coins)

for (turn in 1:num_turns) {
  for (coin in 1:num_coins) {
    results[turn, coin] <- paste("Heads: ", cumulative_heads[turn, coin], ", Tails: ", cumulative_tails[turn, coin])
  }
}
```

The final results look something like this (a sample):

```
> results[1:5, 1:5]
                  coin1                 coin2                 coin3                 coin4                 coin5
1 Heads:  1 , Tails:  0 Heads:  0 , Tails:  1 Heads:  1 , Tails:  0 Heads:  1 , Tails:  0 Heads:  1 , Tails:  0
2 Heads:  1 , Tails:  1 Heads:  0 , Tails:  2 Heads:  2 , Tails:  0 Heads:  2 , Tails:  0 Heads:  2 , Tails:  0
3 Heads:  1 , Tails:  2 Heads:  0 , Tails:  3 Heads:  3 , Tails:  0 Heads:  3 , Tails:  0 Heads:  2 , Tails:  1
4 Heads:  2 , Tails:  2 Heads:  0 , Tails:  4 Heads:  4 , Tails:  0 Heads:  4 , Tails:  0 Heads:  2 , Tails:  2
5 Heads:  3 , Tails:  2 Heads:  0 , Tails:  5 Heads:  5 , Tails:  0 Heads:  5 , Tails:  0 Heads:  2 , Tails:  3
```

I think I have overcomplicated this - can someone please show me what I can do to simplify this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Idea and Code

You can define a function that **updates** the **selected** coins for flips, e.g.,

```
f <- function(v) {
   selected <- runif(length(v)) <= 0.5
   updated <- v[selected] * (1 - 2 * (runif(sum(selected)) <= 0.6))
   replace(v, selected, updated)
}
```

then we use `Reduce` function (but enable the `accumulate` argument) to keep track of the progress of changes, ***where the updated coin status from the previous iteration will be the taken as the input for the upcoming iteration***

```
set.seed(0)
num_coins <- 100
num_turns <- 100
v <- sample(c(1, -1), num_coins, TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
p <- Reduce(\(x, y) f(x), seq.int(num_turns), init = v, accumulate = TRUE)
```

Finally, if you would like to obtain the cumulative statistics of the heads and tails of each coin, you can first `rbind` the outcomes of `p`, and then analyze the distribution of heads and tails by column, e.g.,

```
out <- apply(
   do.call(rbind, p),
   2,
   \(u) data.frame(
      heads = cumsum(u == 1),
      tails = cumsum(u == -1)
   )
)
```

## Output

The outcome of the first `6` turns (incl. `turn=0`) is shown as below

```
> head(p)
[[1]]
  [1]  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1
 [26] -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1
 [51]  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1
 [76] -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1

[[2]]
  [1]  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1
 [26] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1
 [51]  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1
 [76] -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1

[[3]]
  [1] -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1
 [26]  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1
 [51]  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1
 [76] -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1

[[4]]
  [1] -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1
 [26] -1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1
 [51]  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1
 [76] -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1

[[5]]
  [1] -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1
 [26]  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
 [51]  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1
 [76]  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1

[[6]]
  [1]  1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1
 [26]  1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
 [51] -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1
 [76]  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1
```

and the updating progress of the first `6` coins

```
> head(out)
[[1]]
    heads tails
1       1     0
2       2     0
3       2     1
4       2     2
5       2     3
6       3     3
7       3     4
8       3     5
9       3     6
10      3     7
11      4     7
12      5     7
13      6     7
14      7     7
15      7     8
16      8     8
17      9     8
18     10     8
19     11     8
20     12     8
21     12     9
22     12    10
23     12    11
24     12    12
25     12    13
26     12    14
27     12    15
28     12    16
29     12    17
30     13    17
31     13    18
32     14    18
33     15    18
34     16    18
35     17    18
36     17    19
37     17    20
38     17    21
39     17    22
40     17    23
41     17    24
42     17    25
43     17    26
44     18    26
45     19    26
46     20    26
47     21    26
48     22    26
49     23    26
50     23    27
51     23    28
52     23    29
53     24    29
54     24    30
55     24    31
56     24    32
57     24    33
58     24    34
59     24    35
60     24    36
61     24    37
62     24    38
63     25    38
64     26    38
65     27    38
66     28    38
67     29    38
68     30    38
69     31    38
70     32    38
71     33    38
72     33    39
73     33    40
74     33    41
75     33    42
76     33    43
77     33    44
78     34    44
79     35    44
80     36    44
81     37    44
82     37    45
83     37    46
84     37    47
85     38    47
86     39    47
87     40    47
88     41    47
89     41    48
90     41    49
91     41    50
92     41    51
93     42    51
94     43    51
95     44    51
96     44    52
97     44    53
98     44    54
99     44    55
100    44    56
101    45    56

[[2]]
    heads tails
1       0     1
2       0     2
3       1     2
4       2     2
5       2     3
6       2     4
7       3     4
8       4     4
9       4     5
10      4     6
11      4     7
12      4     8
13      4     9
14      4    10
15      4    11
16      4    12
17      5    12
18      6    12
19      6    13
20      6    14
21      7    14
22      7    15
23      7    16
24      7    17
25      7    18
26      7    19
27      7    20
28      7    21
29      7    22
30      7    23
31      8    23
32      9    23
33     10    23
34     10    24
35     11    24
36     12    24
37     13    24
38     14    24
39     15    24
40     16    24
41     17    24
42     18    24
43     18    25
44     18    26
45     18    27
46     18    28
47     18    29
48     18    30
49     19    30
50     19    31
51     20    31
52     21    31
53     21    32
54     21    33
55     21    34
56     21    35
57     21    36
58     21    37
59     21    38
60     22    38
61     23    38
62     24    38
63     24    39
64     24    40
65     24    41
66     25    41
67     26    41
68     27    41
69     28    41
70     29    41
71     29    42
72     29    43
73     29    44
74     29    45
75     30    45
76     30    46
77     30    47
78     31    47
79     32    47
80     33    47
81     34    47
82     35    47
83     36    47
84     37    47
85     37    48
86     37    49
87     37    50
88     37    51
89     37    52
90     38    52
91     39    52
92     40    52
93     41    52
94     42    52
95     43    52
96     43    53
97     44    53
98     45    53
99     46    53
100    47    53
101    48    53

[[3]]
    heads tails
1       0     1
2       0     2
3       1     2
4       2     2
5       3     2
6       4     2
7       4     3
8       4     4
9       4     5
10      4     6
11      4     7
12      5     7
13      5     8
14      5     9
15      5    10
16      6    10
17      7    10
18      8    10
19      9    10
20     10    10
21     11    10
22     12    10
23     13    10
24     14    10
25     15    10
26     16    10
27     16    11
28     16    12
29     17    12
30     18    12
31     19    12
32     19    13
33     19    14
34     19    15
35     19    16
36     20    16
37     21    16
38     22    16
39     23    16
40     24    16
41     25    16
42     25    17
43     26    17
44     27    17
45     28    17
46     28    18
47     28    19
48     28    20
49     29    20
50     30    20
51     31    20
52     32    20
53     32    21
54     32    22
55     32    23
56     32    24
57     32    25
58     33    25
59     34    25
60     35    25
61     36    25
62     37    25
63     38    25
64     39    25
65     40    25
66     40    26
67     40    27
68     40    28
69     41    28
70     41    29
71     42    29
72     43    29
73     44    29
74     45    29
75     46    29
76     47    29
77     48    29
78     49    29
79     50    29
80     51    29
81     51    30
82     51    31
83     51    32
84     52    32
85     53    32
86     53    33
87     54    33
88     54    34
89     55    34
90     56    34
91     57    34
92     58    34
93     59    34
94     60    34
95     61    34
96     61    35
97     61    36
98     61    37
99     62    37
100    63    37
101    64    37

[[4]]
    heads tails
1       1     0
2       1     1
3       2     1
4       3     1
5       4     1
6       5     1
7       5     2
8       6     2
9       7     2
10      7     3
11      8     3
12      9     3
13      9     4
14     10     4
15     10     5
16     10     6
17     10     7
18     11     7
19     11     8
20     11     9
21     11    10
22     11    11
23     11    12
24     12    12
25     13    12
26     13    13
27     13    14
28     13    15
29     13    16
30     13    17
31     14    17
32     15    17
33     16    17
34     16    18
35     16    19
36     16    20
37     16    21
38     17    21
39     18    21
40     18    22
41     18    23
42     18    24
43     18    25
44     18    26
45     18    27
46     18    28
47     18    29
48     18    30
49     18    31
50     18    32
51     18    33
52     18    34
53     18    35
54     18    36
55     19    36
56     20    36
57     21    36
58     21    37
59     21    38
60     21    39
61     21    40
62     21    41
63     22    41
64     23    41
65     24    41
66     25    41
67     26    41
68     27    41
69     27    42
70     28    42
71     29    42
72     30    42
73     31    42
74     32    42
75     32    43
76     32    44
77     32    45
78     32    46
79     33    46
80     34    46
81     35    46
82     36    46
83     36    47
84     36    48
85     37    48
86     38    48
87     38    49
88     39    49
89     40    49
90     41    49
91     41    50
92     42    50
93     43    50
94     44    50
95     45    50
96     46    50
97     46    51
98     47    51
99     47    52
100    47    53
101    47    54

[[5]]
    heads tails
1       1     0
2       2     0
3       3     0
4       4     0
5       5     0
6       6     0
7       7     0
8       7     1
9       8     1
10      9     1
11     10     1
12     11     1
13     12     1
14     12     2
15     13     2
16     14     2
17     14     3
18     14     4
19     14     5
20     15     5
21     15     6
22     15     7
23     15     8
24     15     9
25     15    10
26     15    11
27     15    12
28     16    12
29     16    13
30     16    14
31     16    15
32     16    16
33     16    17
34     16    18
35     17    18
36     18    18
37     19    18
38     20    18
39     21    18
40     22    18
41     23    18
42     24    18
43     25    18
44     26    18
45     27    18
46     27    19
47     27    20
48     27    21
49     28    21
50     28    22
51     29    22
52     30    22
53     30    23
54     31    23
55     31    24
56     31    25
57     31    26
58     31    27
59     31    28
60     32    28
61     33    28
62     33    29
63     33    30
64     34    30
65     34    31
66     34    32
67     34    33
68     35    33
69     36    33
70     37    33
71     38    33
72     39    33
73     40    33
74     41    33
75     42    33
76     43    33
77     44    33
78     44    34
79     44    35
80     44    36
81     44    37
82     44    38
83     44    39
84     44    40
85     44    41
86     45    41
87     45    42
88     45    43
89     46    43
90     47    43
91     48    43
92     48    44
93     48    45
94     48    46
95     49    46
96     50    46
97     51    46
98     51    47
99     51    48
100    52    48
101    53    48

[[6]]
    heads tails
1       0     1
2       0     2
3       0     3
4       0     4
5       0     5
6       0     6
7       1     6
8       2     6
9       2     7
10      3     7
11      3     8
12      3     9
13      3    10
14      3    11
15      3    12
16      3    13
17      3    14
18      4    14
19      4    15
20      4    16
21      4    17
22      4    18
23      4    19
24      5    19
25      6    19
26      6    20
27      7    20
28      8    20
29      8    21
30      8    22
31      9    22
32     10    22
33     11    22
34     11    23
35     11    24
36     11    25
37     12    25
38     12    26
39     12    27
40     12    28
41     12    29
42     12    30
43     12    31
44     12    32
45     12    33
46     13    33
47     14    33
48     14    34
49     14    35
50     15    35
51     16    35
52     17    35
53     17    36
54     17    37
55     17    38
56     17    39
57     18    39
58     19    39
59     20    39
60     20    40
61     20    41
62     21    41
63     22    41
64     23    41
65     23    42
66     24    42
67     24    43
68     25    43
69     26    43
70     27    43
71     28    43
72     29    43
73     29    44
74     29    45
75     29    46
76     29    47
77     29    48
78     29    49
79     29    50
80     29    51
81     29    52
82     29    53
83     30    53
84     31    53
85     32    53
86     32    54
87     32    55
88     32    56
89     32    57
90     32    58
91     32    59
92     33    59
93     34    59
94     35    59
95     36    59
96     37    59
97     38    59
98     39    59
99     40    59
100    40    60
101    41    60
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Do you have any idea about this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78156582/taking-screenshots-from-stackoverflow-using-r

Answer (score 1):

### Just sample a big matrix of 1's and 0's and add them all together

First, we create a 100-by-100 matrix of flip probabilities, where each column is a coin and each row is a flip. We can calculate a simplified probability of flipping by combining the two steps of coin-selection and flipping into one fixed 'probability for flipping over'. A flip is `1`, and a non-flip is `0`.

```r
set.seed(123)
# Probability of flipping over is p(flipping at all) * p(flipping over) (i.e. 0.5 * 0.4 = 0.2)
flips <- rbinom(10000, 1, 0.2)
dim(flips) <- c(100, 100)
```

We then add an initial row to the top of our matrix, with a random binomial values that represent the initial positions of the coins.

```r
## Initialise flip-matrix with random coin flips
flips <- rbind(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), flips)
```

To simulate the flipping, we just get the cumulative sums of each column in the matrix. In this simulation, even values are heads and odd values are tails. We can use `%%` to derive a logical heads/tails matrix from our numeric values:

```r
flips <- apply(flips, 2, cumsum)

flips <- flips %% 2 == 0
```

Then we remove the first row (turn 0) before summing heads and tails:

```r
## We don't tally scores for turn zero
flips <- flips[-1, ]

heads <- colSums(flips)
tails <- 100 - heads

scores <- data.frame(coin = 1:100, heads = heads, tails = tails)

head(scores)
#>   coin heads tails
#> 1    1    57    43
#> 2    2    53    47
#> 3    3    31    69
#> 4    4    60    40
#> 5    5    59    41
#> 6    6    50    50
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Here's the full code for convenience

```r
set.seed(123)
# Probability of flipping over is p(flipping at all) * p(flipping over)
flips <- rbinom(10000, 1, 0.2)
dim(flips) <- c(100, 100)

## Initialise flip-matrix with random coin flips
flips <- rbind(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), flips)

flips <- apply(flips, 2, cumsum)

flips <- flips %% 2 == 0

## We don't tally scores for turn zero
flips <- flips[-1, ]

heads <- colSums(flips)
tails <- 100 - heads

scores <- data.frame(coin = 1:100, heads = heads, tails = tails)

head(scores)
#>   coin heads tails
#> 1    1    57    43
#> 2    2    53    47
#> 3    3    31    69
#> 4    4    60    40
#> 5    5    59    41
#> 6    6    50    50
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The comments should be easy enough to follow.

```
set.seed(688396493)
N <- 100 # coins
n <- 100 # turns
ps <- 0.5 # probability of selection
pf <- 0.4 # probability of swapping sides conditioned on a flip
pt <- ps*pf # unconditional probability of swapping sides in a turn
# Initialize the cumulative heads matrix. Turns along rows, coins along columns.
heads <- matrix(0L, n, N, 0, list(paste0("turn", 1:n), paste0("coin", 1:N)))
# state after the first turn (heads = T, tails = F)
heads[1,] <- s <- sample(!0:1, N, 1)
# pre-calculate the number of coins that will swap sides on each turn
nt <- rbinom(n, N, pt)
# complete the simulation
for (i in 2:n) {
  idx <- sample(N, nt[i])
  s[idx] <- !s[idx]
  heads[i,] <- heads[i - 1,] + s
}
# calculate the tails
tails <- 1:n - heads
```

Results of the first 10 turns of the first 10 coins:

```
heads[1:10, 1:10]
#>        coin1 coin2 coin3 coin4 coin5 coin6 coin7 coin8 coin9 coin10
#> turn1      1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1      1
#> turn2      2     2     1     2     0     2     2     0     2      2
#> turn3      3     3     2     3     0     3     3     0     2      2
#> turn4      4     4     3     4     0     3     3     1     2      3
#> turn5      5     5     4     5     0     3     3     2     2      3
#> turn6      5     5     5     5     0     3     4     3     2      3
#> turn7      6     5     5     5     0     3     4     4     2      3
#> turn8      7     5     5     6     0     3     4     5     2      3
#> turn9      8     5     5     7     0     3     4     6     2      3
#> turn10     9     5     6     7     0     4     5     7     2      3
tails[1:10, 1:10]
#>        coin1 coin2 coin3 coin4 coin5 coin6 coin7 coin8 coin9 coin10
#> turn1      0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0      0
#> turn2      0     0     1     0     2     0     0     2     0      0
#> turn3      0     0     1     0     3     0     0     3     1      1
#> turn4      0     0     1     0     4     1     1     3     2      1
#> turn5      0     0     1     0     5     2     2     3     3      2
#> turn6      1     1     1     1     6     3     2     3     4      3
#> turn7      1     2     2     2     7     4     3     3     5      4
#> turn8      1     3     3     2     8     5     4     3     6      5
#> turn9      1     4     4     2     9     6     5     3     7      6
#> turn10     1     5     4     3    10     6     5     3     8      7
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the code into its several steps.

**Step 1**
Flip the coins

1. Flip one coin one turn;
2. Flip one coin n turns;
3. Flip all coins all turns.

```r
flip_one_coin <- function() {
  if (runif(1) < 0.5) {
    # Flip the coin
    if (runif(1) < 0.6) {
      1L      # Coin lands on the same side
    } else {
      -1L     # Coin lands on the other side
    }
  } else -1L  # Coin not selected
}
flip_one_coin_ntimes <- function(n) {
  heads <- tails <- replicate(n, flip_one_coin())
  heads[heads != 1L] <- 0L
  tails[tails != -1L] <- 0L
  list(Heads = cumsum(heads), Tails = -cumsum(tails))
}
flip_all_coins <- function(ncoins, ntimes) {
  replicate(ncoins, flip_one_coin_ntimes(ntimes))
}

num_coins <- 100L
num_turns <- 100L

# test the function and see what it outputs
flip_one_coin_ntimes(num_turns)
#> $Heads
#>   [1]  0  0  0  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  7  8  8
#>  [26]  9 10 10 11 11 11 11 12 13 14 15 15 16 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19
#>  [51] 19 19 20 20 21 21 22 22 22 23 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 26 26 26 27 27 27 28 28
#>  [76] 29 29 29 30 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 32 32 33 33 34 34 34 35 35 36 36 37 37 38
#> 
#> $Tails
#>   [1]  1  2  3  3  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 11 12 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 16 16 17
#>  [26] 17 17 18 18 19 20 21 21 21 21 21 22 22 22 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 30 31
#>  [51] 32 33 33 34 34 35 35 36 37 37 37 38 39 40 41 42 42 42 43 44 44 45 46 46 47
#>  [76] 47 48 49 49 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 55 56 56 57 57 58 59 59 60 60 61 61 62 62
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Step 2**
Put the results in a nicer form, matrices. The heads and tails results are in the final named list.

```r
# these are going to be the end result row and column names
rn <- sprintf("turn_%03d", seq.int(num_turns))
cn <- sprintf("coin_%03d", seq.int(num_coins))

# simulate the flips of all coins
# and create the results' matrices list
results_mat <- flip_all_coins(num_coins, num_turns) |> t()
results <- lapply(c("Heads", "Tails"), \(x) {
  results_mat[, x] |>
    t() |> 
    do.call(cbind, args = _) |>
    `dimnames<-`(list(rn, cn))
}) |>
  `names<-`( c("Heads", "Tails") )

results$Heads[1:5, 1:5]
#>          coin_001 coin_002 coin_003 coin_004 coin_005
#> turn_001        0        0        1        0        0
#> turn_002        0        1        2        0        0
#> turn_003        0        2        2        0        0
#> turn_004        0        2        3        0        0
#> turn_005        1        2        3        0        1
results$Tails[1:5, 1:5]
#>          coin_001 coin_002 coin_003 coin_004 coin_005
#> turn_001        1        1        0        1        1
#> turn_002        2        1        0        2        2
#> turn_003        3        1        1        3        3
#> turn_004        4        2        1        4        4
#> turn_005        4        3        2        5        4
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>